# Input Special Character '%' in to Power Automate Desktop Set variable

Tags: character, power-automate, rpa

I have tried to input % in to my variable as text using Set variable method. It is throwing syntax error:-

[image]

Comment: Needs to be %%, I believe.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/variable-manipulation

Comment: It is worked, Thank you. @Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbol **%** is reserved for initialization of the variables, so you always should add additional % to have a double percentage (**%%**). Please double check the code created with other tools before import (especially related to SAP GUI or some JS), because usually such code have a single symbol, which will cause the same error msg.